# Change link colour when hovered on a div, but also change link colour when the link is hovered over

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

Sorry if the title is a bit specific, but this will put the finishing touch on my website. Here is my current code:

```css
.social {
 background-color: rgba(150,150,150,0.75);
 height: 150px;
 width:200px;
 margin: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
    transition: background .25s ease, box-shadow 0.20s ease-in-out, color 0.20s ease;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
.social:hover {
 
    background-color: rgb(118, 118, 118);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 3px rgba(125,125,125,0.75);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    
}

.social:hover a {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
a {
    color: rgb(20, 0, 255);
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 10);
    text-decoration: underline;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="social"> <span>Blank</span>  <br> <span> Blank</span> <p> <a href="http://www.twitter.com"> Hello <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a> <a href="http://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a> <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></p> </div>
```

When I hover over the div, it goes grey, and the text goes white, which is what I want. However, I want it so that, when you hover over the link, it will go lime green.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited your sample.

you need to specify the hover on the `<a>` as well while hovering over the div

```css
.social {
 background-color: rgba(150,150,150,0.75);
 height: 150px;
 width:200px;
 margin: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
    transition: background .25s ease, box-shadow 0.20s ease-in-out, color 0.20s ease;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
.social:hover {
 
    background-color: rgb(118, 118, 118);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 3px rgba(125,125,125,0.75);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    
}

.social:hover a {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
.social:hover a:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 10);
}
a {
    color: rgb(20, 0, 255);
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="social"> <span>Blank</span>  <br> <span> Blank</span> <p> <a href="http://www.twitter.com"> Hello <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a> <a href="http://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a> <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></p> </div>
```